# How do you put an array into an object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Given an object like:

```
[{"name": "Adam", "age": 25}, {"name": "Barbara", "age": 23}]
```

What is the best way to transform it into this:

```
{people: [{"name": "Adam", "age": 25}, {"name": "Barbara", "age": 23}]}
```

?

Comment: The summary has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Sorry about using the wrong terminology, let me know how I should have worded the question and I will see if I can edit it

Comment: How to put an array into an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var src = [{"name": "Adam", "age": 25}, {"name": "Barbara", "age": 23}];

var obj = {people: src};
```